# Adding react-native-windows support for an existing React Native project

Tags: react-native, react-native-windows

We have an ongoing React Native mobile development project targeting Android and iOS. Now a requirement has come to use the app under Windows environment. There is not much information on the web we could found on this.

If we can get some insight on the complexity, pitfalls and challenges in adding windows platform for an already existing React Native project, that will be immensely helpful.

- We are using Hermes and we understand the support is still experimental
- Realm support is not clear. Realm has support for UWP but is it in a stage where we can use in production level?
- How much support is available under windows for other 3rd party libraries
- How much code will be able to share between platforms. Will we have to write lot of native level code?
- Would react-native-web be more safe bet, if that is an acceptable option for our customer

So far we went through the documents available on web such as

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-environment/javascript/react-native-for-windows

https://microsoft.github.io/react-native-windows/docs/hermes

https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/432

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/dotnet/#std-label-dotnet_supported-platforms

However, have to provide a time estimate and cost benefit analysis before actually implementing it. Thats why we would like to get some insigth from someone who has already done it.